# Returns invalid table from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I use MS SQL Server and EF Core 6.

This is the code for my stored procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Ingredient_Select]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        dbo.Products.Id, dbo.Products.Name AS Product,
        dbo.Materials.Name AS Material, dbo.Ingredients.Count
    FROM
        dbo.Ingredients 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Products ON dbo.Ingredients.Product = dbo.Products.Id 
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.Materials ON dbo.Ingredients.Material = dbo.Materials.Id
END
```

[image: sql table]

This is how I call the stored procedure via EF Core:

```cs
List<Ingredient> ingredients = await _context.Ingredients
    .FromSqlRaw<Ingredient>("SP_Ingredient_Select").ToListAsync();

return View(ingredients);
```

[image]

Entity `Ingredient`:

```cs
public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? Product { get; set; }
    public string? Material { get; set; }
    public double? Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you set up `Ingredient.Id` as a primary key on the EF side?

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Yes, I have a PC configured on the EF Core side.

Comment: just got rid of the prefix, but nothing helped

Comment: You're not showing the IDs in your 2nd data list.  Please include them.

Comment: UPD: I updated 2 table

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was that my visible procedure was choosing products.id instead of ingredients.id

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of possibilities here, including:

1. You are using two different security contexts (login/user) and there some security filtering that is resulting in different data, or
2. Your EF is connecting to a different database or server than the first query execution in your post. It is not uncommon for client programs to connect to test, QA or Production copies of a database without the user realizing it, because there's no visible indication in most programs to tell them what DB/server they are really connecting to.
3. The client context isn't defaulting to using the DBO schema.  This is a login/user setting, but is rarely used so it can be confusing.

There are other possibilities as well.